# Datatable is not working when there is data from DB

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

Jquery datatable plugin is not working when it has data that selected from database by date. But it's working if there is no data in table. Here some code

Select all data from database table in controller :

```
$inbound['inbound'] = DB::table('REPORT_INBOUND')
    ->where('regdate', '=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2019-05-21")))
    ->get();
return view('/traffic', $inbound, $outbound);
```

And i did copy paste that necessary scripts for example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

```
<table id="ahhhaa" width="90%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover display">
            <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>RegDate</th>
                <th>HPMN Code</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>HPMN Name</th>
            </tr>
            </head>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($inbound as $value)
                <tr class="table table-hover">
                    <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->regdate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->hpmn_code }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->country }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->hpmn_name }}</td>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#ahhhaa').DataTable()
});
```

Is there any error ?

Comment: is this server data table ?

Comment: did you include the data table js and CSS files?

Comment: show us your php code(backend code loop) too

Comment: Added some code guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because u did not close your `thead`.

Fix this and comment if not solved .

```
<table id="ahhhaa" width="90%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover 
display">
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>RegDate</th>
            <th>HPMN Code</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>HPMN Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead><!-- Add this Line -->
        <tbody>
            loop...
        </tbody>
```

Hope this works !

Answer (score 0):

return your view page with data:

```
return view('folder/file_name')->with($inbound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the id of the table.Otherwise the laravel will not identify the table as a datatable.

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-responsive">
```